# What quality level does Image.Save() use for jpeg files?

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing.imaging

I just got a real surprise when I loaded a jpg file and turned around and saved it with a quality of 100 and the size was almost 4x the original.  To further investigate I open and saved without explicitly setting the quality and the file size was exactly the same.  I figured this was because nothing changed so it's just writing the exact same bits back to a file.  To test this assumption I drew a big fat line diagonally across the image and saved again without setting quality (this time I expected the file to jump up because it would be "dirty") but it decreased ~10Kb!

At this point I really don't understand what is happening when I simply call Image.Save() w/out specifying a compression quality.  How is the file size so close (after the image is modified) to the original size when no quality is set yet when I set quality to 100 (basically no compression) the file size is several times larger than the original?

I've read the documentation on Image.Save() and it's lacking any detail about what is happening behind the scenes.  I've googled every which way I can think of but I can't find any additional information that would explain what I'm seeing.  I have been working for 31 hours straight so maybe I'm missing something obvious ;0)

All of this has come about while I implement some library methods to save images to a database.  I've overloaded our "SaveImage" method to allow explicitly setting a quality and during my testing I came across the odd (to me) results explained above.  Any light you can shed will be appreciated.

Here is some code that will illustrate what I'm experiencing:

```
string filename = @"C:\temp\image testing\hh.jpg";
string destPath = @"C:\temp\image testing\";

using(Image image = Image.FromFile(filename))
{
    ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = ImageUtils.GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    //  Set the quality
    EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    // Quality: 10
    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 10L);
    image.Save(destPath + "10.jpg", codecInfo, parameters);

    // Quality: 75
    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 75L);
    image.Save(destPath + "75.jpg", codecInfo, parameters);

    // Quality: 100
    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
    image.Save(destPath + "100.jpg", codecInfo, parameters);

    //  default
    image.Save(destPath + "default.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    //  Big line across image
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 50F))
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
        }
    }

    image.Save(destPath + "big red line.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat format)
{
    return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().ToList().Find(delegate(ImageCodecInfo codec)
    {
        return codec.FormatID == format.Guid;
    });
}
```

Comment: I did some experiments about the compressions for JPG in .NET and the corresponding errors, see http://www.c4real.biz/jpgCompression.aspx.

Comment: Based on some quick testing, it seems that your original intuition is correct: if you have an Image that was originally jpg and call Save without specifying quality, it'll just dump the original bits out to the file. If you've modified the image in memory, or if you request a particular compression level, it will re-encode the image. If you request a high quality level for an image that came from a low-quality source, you're wasting a lot of space trying to very accurately describe all of the artifacts introduced by the original compression.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using reflector, it turns out `Image.Save()` boils down to the GDI+ function [GdipSaveImageToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534041%28VS.85%29.aspx), with the `encoderParams` NULL. So I think the question is what the JPEG encoder does when it gets a null `encoderParams`. 75% has been suggested here, but I can't find any solid reference.

**EDIT** You could probably find out for yourself by running your program above for quality values of 1..100 and comparing them with the jpg saved with the default quality (using, say, fc.exe /B)

Comment: Ah, I forgot about reflector! ;0)  Good to know there is no mysterious magic happening in that method.  I think I will do a test as you suggested just to set my mind at ease.  I will report the results here on this thread.

Comment: I did a quick test and opened a *.bmp file, then saved to jpg with default settings and also with a quality explicitly set to 75.  The files are EXACTLY the same size.  So it must be that the encoder is internally defaulting to 75.  I think this should be in the documentation somewhere, don't you guys?

Comment: Definitely, but I'm not sure *which* documentation. As far as I understand, it is a feature of the default windows JPEG encoder, whose documentation resides in a place unknown to me...

Comment: I looked here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.jpeg.aspx before finding this question. So I would have expected that to have either the answer or a link to some other documentation with the answer.

Comment: I believe it uses quality=100 as the default, which is horrible... you need to use quality=90 to get decent behavior.

Comment: This is the documentation about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.quality.aspx

Comment: @ComputerLinguist: Your comment doesn't make any sense. Quality 100 is better than quality 90.

Answer (score 6):

IIRC, it is 75%, but I dont recall where I read this.

Comment: I've used his method to save as 75L and I saved another with the default. Result: `75L = 36.7 KB` and `default = 36.8 KB`. If it is not 75% then it is like 75.1%...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the Image.Save method, but I can tell you that adding that fat line would logicly reduce the size of the jpg image. This is due to the way a jpg is saved (and encoded).

The thick black line makes for a very simple and smaller encoding (If I remember correctly this is relevent mostly after the Discrete cosine transform), so the modified image can be stored using less data (bytes).

[jpg encoding steps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Encoding)

Regarding the changes in size (without the added line), I'm not sure which image you reopened and resaved

> To further investigate I open and saved without explicitly setting the quality and the file size was exactly the same

If you opened the old (original normal size) image and resaved it, then maybe the default compression and the original image compression are the same.
If you opened the new (4X larger) image and resaved it, then maybe the default compression for the save method is derived from the image (as it was when loaded).

Again, I don't know the save method, so I'm just throwing ideas (maybe they'll give you a lead).

Comment: You're right, it makes perfect sense that a large, solid region would compress efficiently.  What I was trying to accomplish and should have explained better is to force a re-encoding of the data.  I was trying to determine if I was seeing the same file size because Save() was doing a straight dump of bits to disk.  I figured if I stomped across the image and then saved it would trigger the file to be re-encoded.  Thanks for the links and additional information.