# read jpeg without quality loss

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

I have an jpeg image 720x480 8BPP with a quality of 95%.
 If I open this image with IrfanView and type "i" to get the information to this image I can see that this image has 238 unique colors.
If I open this image in C# with

```
Image image1 = Image.FromFile("J:\\test.jpg", true);
```

and count the unique colors, I always count only 16. Also when I save this image regardless of JPG or BMP, if I opend this saved image with IrfanView and look to the info I see only 16 unique colors.
What is the reason for that?

Best regards
Michael

Comment: You can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195642/losing-image-quality-in-c-sharp-using-image-class-reduces-amount-of-colors

Comment: I read this article but the image.LoadFrom method with second parameter = true doesn't work for me.

Comment: Is this a grayscale image then? 8BPP.

Comment: Yes it is. (jpeg image 720x480 8BPP with a quality of 95%)