# Delphi(x3 Bigger) Jpeg vs .NET(x1 Small) Jpeg FileSize

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, graphics, jpeg

.net c# code

```
    var mimage = new MemoryStream();
    my_image.Save(mimage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Delphi code

```
//bSource HAS THE ORIGINAL IMAGE
bSource := Tbitmap.Create;
//...
//CODES HERE...
//...
//CODES HERE...
//...
bDest := Tbitmap.Create;
bDest.SetSize(r.width , r.height );
bDest.Canvas.FillRect(bDest.Canvas.ClipRect);
//CODES HERE...
//bDest HAS THE IMAGE FROM <<< bSource >>>>
//CODES HERE..
bSource.Free;
jDest := TJpegImage.Create;
jDest.ProgressiveEncoding:=true;
jDest.CompressionQuality :=100;
jDest.Smoothing := True;
jDest.PixelFormat := jf24bit;
jDest.Compress;
jDest.Assign(bDest); //bDest COPY
jDest.SaveToFile('BIG_FILESIZE_THAN.NET.JPEGx3.jpg');  //FILE SIZE IS TIMES 3 BIGGER THAN .NET
jDest.Free;
bDest.Free;
```

> Same image to compare During Saved
>
> Delphi has Filesize of 5k with 200x200 8bpp = BIGGER?
>
> .Net has Filesize of 2k with 200x200 24bpp = SMALLER?

What has to be done in Delphi to make it like the size of .NET?

Comment: In Delphi try setting the CompressionQuality to 75 and should be comparable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957477/what-quality-level-does-image-save-use-for-jpeg-files

Comment: Didn't you specifically request bigger file size?

Answer (score 3):

By default, because it is not specified, the C# code uses a compression quality level of 75 or so ([What quality level does Image.Save() use for jpeg files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957477/what-quality-level-does-image-save-use-for-jpeg-files)).

Your Delphi code uses a quality level of 100. Hence the image produced by the Delphi code has better quality but is also larger. Specify a lower quality level to reduce the file size.